# Visual Studio c++ Game template/workload missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, game-development

Visual Studio Community 2022:

After installing "Game Development with C++" workload, it doesn't appear in the list of available templates in "Create a new project". I've reinstalled it, and restarted Windows. Does anyone know if this should result in a specific game template? If so, how I might fix this?

VS 2022 is updated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is something to ask at the Microsoft forums.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/tools-pc/visualstudio/gr-vs-templates) there should be a "Microsoft Game Development Kit".  Poke a round and see if you can find it. If you can't, you probably need to install it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Game Development with C++ workload provides DirectX template.

[image].

To get game template, you need to download GDK from doc: [Microsoft Game Development Kit development downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/development-downloads/development-downloads-gdk)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a basic DirectX Win32 template, thinking that Game Workload would be it. Will probably just roll my own or borrow from the 'net.

Comment: By the way, here is  [DirectX Win32 sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop) from  GitHub.